# How to stop refresh the page form the beforeunload event?

Tags: javascript, browser

i'm using the 'beforeunload' event to detect the refresh event from the webpage.how to stop refresh the page from beforeunload event and i should not show alert message

```js
 window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload);


onUnload = e => { 
    e.preventDefault();
  // how to stop refresh the page from here and i should not show alert message.

   //it is showing alert message. i no need to show the alert.
    e.returnValue = "sure do you want to reload?";   
    
 }
```

Comment: you can't, if you could, the internet whould be terrible place.

Comment: I dont really understand your question, do you want the alert, or do you just want prevent the user from refreshing?

Comment: i want to prevent refreshing and instered of showing default alert i want to show modal.In there i have two buttons ok and cancel. if user clicks ok ill reload the page there. if user clicks cancel i'll close the modal

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to prevent unloading a page without notifying the user.

Imagine you want to go to github.com at a time you are viewing stackoverflow.com - but it will simply prevent you from navigating away!

However, there was a time some browsers used to prevent unloading silently when you assign an empty string to the `returnValue`. But I believe that age of evil is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

When i understand your following comment corectly, then you simply need to return zero, or false. So in your function you write:

```
onUnload = e => { 
//e.preventDefault();
return false;
}
```

When i do this, i get an automated response from the Browser (for me its Chrome), if i really wanna close this website. And its in my language, so its i18n-compilant

It basically says "Are you sure you wanna refresh/close this website, data may get lost" and than 2 buttons with "Refresh/Close" and "Abort"
[image: This is what im seeing]